# Converting TinkerKit to native Arduino pins

Tags: pins, port-mapping

Over the years, I have acquired many TinkerKit modules for my Arduino Uno. My only issue is that I need to find a way to code using the native syntax, and not the less-powerful TinkerKit variation. To do this, I need to know if TinkerKit maps its 3-pin connector to the Arduino Board's pins (ex: 1, 3, 5). If it does, what are the mappings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [TinkerKit Sensor Shield](https://store.arduino.cc/product/T020010) helps understand the mapping. There is also the [TinkerKit Header File](https://github.com/TinkerKit/TinkerKit/blob/master/TinkerKit.h) with symbol mapping.